# A Householder matrix as a product of Givens matrices

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

I am working on the following problem:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $H$ be a Householder matrix such that $Hx = \|x\|_2e_1$. Let $G_{1,2}, \ldots, G_{1,n}$ be Givens rotation matrices such that $Gx = G_{1,n} \cdots G_{1,2}x = \|x\|_2e_1$. Is $G$ equal to $H$?

My idea: Since $H$ is a Householder matrix, it is unitary, so $H^TH = I$. If we multiply both sides of $Hx = Gx$ by $H^T$ then we obtain $H^TGx = x$. Based on this, I guess $H$ does not have to be equal to $G$; the only thing we need is that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $H^TG$. Can you guys give me a hint? I am having troubles to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: $\mathbf x$ is real and $\mathbf e_1$ is the first standard basis vector (real) so $H$ is real... why do you introduce words like Hermitian?  $H^*H=I$ is defining for unitary, not Hermitian, but again this seems to be over reals so just write $H^TH =I$ and $H$ is orthogonal (and it is also symmetric).  Also it occurs to me the checking determinants could be useful here...

Comment: can you compute $\det\big(H\big)$ and $\det\big(G_{i,n}\big)$ for arbitrary Householder and Givens matrices?

Comment: @user8675309 yes, I can but I do not see how this is related to the problem.

Comment: now that I think about it, $\det(H) = -1$ and $\det(G_{i,n}) = 1$. Am I right?

Comment: yes. so $\det\big(G\big) = 1\cdot 1\cdot... \cdot 1 = 1 \neq -1=\det\big(H\big)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a counterexample, here is probably the simplest one. Let $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider $c:=\cos\phi$ and $s:=\sin\phi$. Set
$$
H:=\begin{bmatrix}c&s\\s&-c\end{bmatrix}, \quad G:=\begin{bmatrix}c&s\\-s&c\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The matrix $H$ is a reflection and $G$ is a rotation.
Clearly $H\neq G$, even though
$$
H\begin{bmatrix}c\\s\end{bmatrix}
=G\begin{bmatrix}c\\s\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

The rotation matrix $G$ is clearly a Givens rotation. We just need to show that the reflection $H$ is a Householder reflection, that is, it is of the form $H=I-2vv^T$ with $v:=[v_1,v_2]^T$, such that $\|v\|_2^2=v_1^2+v_2^2=1$.

This can be verified by comparing the equation $I-2vv^T$ with the defining expression for $H$:
$$
1-2v_1^2=c,\quad 1-2v_2^2=c, \quad s=-2v_1v_2.
$$
You can guess the solution from the first two equations and then adjust the signs of $v_1$ and $v_2$ in order to satisfy the last one.
For example, one solution is
$$
v_1=-\mathrm{sgn}(s)\sqrt{\frac{1-c}{2}}, \quad
v_2=\sqrt{\frac{1+c}{2}}.
$$